# Laravel 9 Gate "Too few arguments to function App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::App\Providers\{closure}()..."

Tags: php, laravel

I have an `Evaluation` model that has a relationship to a `User`.  I am trying to use Laravel Gates to protect the evaluation routes by allowing only the assigned users to access their evaluation(s).  I have never used Gates before and cannot seem to get one to work and keep getting a `Too few arguments to function App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::App\Providers\{closure}(), 1 passed in /Users/charles/Documents/Development/seedgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php on line 536 and exactly 2 expected` error.  I understand I need to pass in additional arguments, but I am stuck.

**AuthServiceProvidor.php**

```
...
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('showEval', function (User $user, Evaluation $evaluation) {
        return $user->id === $evaluation->user_id;
    });
}
...
```

**Show.php**

```
...
public function render()
{

    if (Gate::allows('showEval')) {
        return view('livewire.evaluation.show');
    } else {
        abort(403);
    }

}
...
```

Comment: Perhaps this helps, otherwise I have no clue: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/too-few-argments-to-function-authserviceprovider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't pass the `$evaluation` to check in gate

```php
public function render()
{
    // somehow getting $evaluation you want to pass to gate check
    if (Gate::allows('showEval', $evaluation)) {
        return view('livewire.evaluation.show');
    } else {
        abort(403);
    }

}
```

according to [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#authorizing-actions-via-gates) gate takes current user by itself, so passing second param is on you